# Shares from facebook fan page to show 'via' appname

Tags: facebook

How can I make all shares from my facebook page to be shown in users timeline as shared 
'via my_app_name' ?

Comment: I think its by default in nature

Answer (score 0):

That will be done when the shares are actually done by your real app. You cannot add 'via my_app_name' on your own.

**For example:**

If you play a level on Angry Birds, and get a new high score. It will be saved there and the app name will be saved, or when you upload or post a new content on Twitter or Tumblr, you will see that there is the name of app too. Otherwise facebook just lets you edit your 'feeling...' 'in...' 'with...' but not 'via...'.

**Create an app:**

You can create the app, and then use it to share content! You can check out there developer documents to let your app share content from web or facebook on your timeline! This way, users will see your content being shared 'via my_app_name'.

**Bravo!**

Once done! It will automatically do the job for you to show the 'via...' thing. Else facebook won't allow you to edit that and every post will not have the 'via...' object saved in it!

Comment: Currently i am not connected with any app for my page, if I create a new app how can I make this working?

Comment: You can first: **Create an app** from here https://developers.facebook.com/apps and then edit the app so that it can share the content on the timelines of the users. Facebook will let you have a space on Heroku or somewhere else. To place the code for your app. Once in that app, whenever you have some activity it will shared as: "your_name has a new activity .. via my_app_name"